# mysqldbcopy command not found

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

I'm getting `-bash: mysqldbcopy: command not found` error even after `sudo su-`.

My MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.25, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Do I need to install `MySQL workbench` with RPM package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a handy CentOS server I have to hand,

```
yum provides */mysqldbcopy
mysql-utilities-1.3.0-1.el6.noarch : MySQL Utilities
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysqldbcopy
```

So (if it's not already installed) you should be able to install it with

```
yum install mysql-utilities
```

You may not have EPEL installed/enabled but there are plenty of [Q&A here](https://serverfault.com/search?q=enable%20EPEL) about it.

Comment: My yum is having checksum issues where CentOS 5 doesn't seem to be able to understand sha256 so I have downloaded RPM to my server. Is there a good link with instructions for installing this package?

Comment: @JaeChoi: man rpm ; in particlar rpm -i

Comment: i like this command